# Where to point website with Zeo server in Plone

Tags: plone

I've installed ZEO for first time. In my configuration, instance services HTTP request on port 8060. The ZEO server is running on port 8061 and another instance (client) running on 8062. I can access both clients via HTTP in my browser.

My website is pointing to 8060 before I added ZEO and continues to point to 8060 after I added the ZEO server. If I restart 8062 client then it seems my site is still serving pages but if I restart instance on 8060 then website stops serving pages. It seems to me that only 8060 instance is working standalone and not using ZEO as I expect to get a response while restarting any instance. Please note that in the ZEO log I can see hand shaking entries.

Do I have to point website to ZEO server port (which is not serving HTTP request), or am I missing something in the implementation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding a ZEO server does not magically make your website balance between the clients. Your ZEO setup is working just fine, as are your instances, but you need to configure another component: a load balancer.

Whatever you have *in front* of your Plone site needs to be told to use the other client too, this does not happen automatically, and it is not the responsibility of the ZEO server.

What you use as a load balancer is up to you. You have a multitude of options:

- If you currently use Apache to rewrite URLs to your Plone site, you could configure [`mod_rewrite` to load balance](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/advanced.html) to do random load balancing. Or you could use [`mod_proxy_balancer`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html) to implement a more sophisticated balancing setup and add health checking (stop using a backend if it is restarting).
- Varnish can do both caching *and* [load balancing](https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/LoadBalancing) as well.
- You could install a dedicated load balancer. [HAProxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/) would be an excellent choice, and can be fine-tuned to match almost any scenario. We use this in large-scale deployments, balancing load across 30 Plone backends.

You'll need to pick one and configure it. If you have trouble with specifics, you could see if https://serverfault.com can help out.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a load balancer in front of your zeo instances. Give haproxy a try.

http://developer.plone.org/reference_manuals/active/deployment/stack.html?highlight=haproxy#background-the-stack

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.recipe.haproxy/1.1.2